# How do I use pandoc to delete the enclosing tags and just extract a branch of an AST?

Tags: pandoc

I have been studying pandoc filters. I think I get it and have done some tutorials but I'm still having trouble wrapping my head around extracting an embedded body tag and converting it to a div tag while deleting all the enclosing paraphernalia

Suppose I have a simple html file:

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>bla</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  Hello World
  </body>
</html>
```

How would I transform it to

```
<div>
Hello World
<div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To leave the `<body>` tags etc, simply run `pandoc` without the `--standalone` (aka `-s`) option. If you've looked into [pandoc filters](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html), you already know how to insert a `div` where you need it.

P.S. If you look at the [pandoc document AST definition](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L94), you see that it's simply some metadata and a list of block elements. The `<body>` tags etc. are all from the [HTML template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/templates/default.html5), not the AST.